# I need an advise to make a chatbot

Tags: chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I need to make a chatbot for my website which answers with the choices and user selects one of them. It can be a facebook chatbot or it can work without any platform. 
I have tried many applications like https://www.intelliticks.com and etc, but they are not free. I tried also to make it by code with the help of RestFB api in Java. With this Api now I am able to give some answers to users but I could not make an bot which answers with choices.
Below is the sample image to explain what I want to do.
Please give any advise or tutorial or code example which can be helpful for me.

[image]

Comment: I feel like this is opinion based so I'll leave it as a comment. Personally I have used python's NLTK (natural language toolkit) to collect a "bag of words", then NLTK has built-in filler word removal algorithms so I would use that to remove any garbage words. From there you can use techniques like tf-idf to see which saved question closest resembles the one the user entered. You can further improve this by adding word sense disambiguation, or converting words to their most base synonym.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is difficult for me to start the python that is why I am looking for something in Java or ready application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DialogFlow is a powerful platform which enables building a conversation on multiple channels (web, Facebook, Telegram) and supports a variety of responses (simple text, multi choice, cards, media content)

It is free, multi-channel and allows to define a Webhook for integrating a backend.

While most channels are free if you want to integrate it in a website you will need a plugin (Kommunicate, Botcopy) as the default Web widget is meant for testing only (but it is very easy to integrate, maybe it is nice to try how users will interact with the bot).

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Adding a chatbot into your website is a two-step process:

1. Create a chatbot - There are some platforms to develop a bot i.e Dialogflow, Amazon Lex, Microsoft bot framework, IBM Watson etc. you can choose according to your need.
2. Deploy it into the website so that visitors can interact with it. Different bot platforms Provide the APIs and SDK to send the queries to the bot. Either you can implement them or choose any third-party services such as [Kommunicate.io](https://www.kommunicate.io/) which provides the code less integration with the bot platforms.

Here are some blogs which you can refer to for more detail.

[Beginners guide to creating chatbot using dialogflow](https://medium.com/engineering-applozic/beginners-guide-to-creating-chatbots-using-dialogflow-f56e9f6ddaf5)

[Integrate Amazon Lex bot into website](https://tutorials.botsfloor.com/integrate-amazon-lex-chatbot-into-website-3d6031a1937b)

[Chatbot with multiple-choice questions](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-create-a-chatbot-with-multiple-chooice-questions/answer/Suraj-Khanduri)

If you want more detail on which bot platform to choose here is the quick [comparison of different bot platforms](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/dialogflow-vs-lex-vs-watson-vs-wit-vs-azure-bot/) available.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Blogs are useful.